# Work with akka-http and mongo-scala-driver

Tags: mongodb, scala, akka, future, akka-http

I want to use `akka-http` and new `mongo-scala-driver` for my rest service.

This code is working

```
val routes = {
  pathPrefix("info") {
    pathEndOrSingleSlash {
      get {
        val mongoClient: MongoClient = MongoClient("mongodb://localhost:27017,localhost:27018,localhost:27019/?replicaSet=rs0")
        val database: MongoDatabase = mongoClient.getDatabase("test")
        val collection: MongoCollection[Document] = database.getCollection("test")
        val future  = collection.find().limit(10).toFuture()
        val list = Await.result(future, Duration(10, TimeUnit.SECONDS))
        complete(list.map(_.toJson()))
      }
    }
  }
}
```

But I want to remove the blocking code `Await.result` and write asynchronous.

How can I do it? Thanks

build.sbt:

```
scalaVersion := "2.12.1"

"org.mongodb.scala" %% "mongo-scala-driver" % "1.2.1"
"com.typesafe.akka" %% "akka-http-core" % "10.0.4"
"com.typesafe.akka" %% "akka-http" % "10.0.4"
```

**UPDATE**

If I change my code:

```
complete(future.map(_.toJson()))
```

I get an error:

```
Error:(160, 36) value toJson is not a member of Seq[org.mongodb.scala.Document]
        complete(future.map(_.toJson()))
```

**UPDATE**

If I change my code:

```
        onComplete(future) {
          case Success(value) => complete(value)
          case Failure(ex)    => complete((InternalServerError, s"An error occurred: ${ex.getMessage}"))
        }
```

I get en error:

```
Error:(166, 47) type mismatch;
found   : Seq[org.mongodb.scala.bson.collection.immutable.Document]
required: akka.http.scaladsl.marshalling.ToResponseMarshallable
          case Success(value) => complete(value)
```

Comment: Something like feature.onComplete? http://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/2.4.4/scala/http/routing-dsl/directives/future-directives/onComplete.html

Comment: If I change my code, I get an error: Error:(166, 47) type mismatch;
found   : Seq[org.mongodb.scala.bson.collection.immutable.Document]
required: akka.http.scaladsl.marshalling.ToResponseMarshallable
          case Success(value) => complete(value)

Comment: Or you can use http://reactivemongo.org/releases/0.12/documentation/

Comment: Ok, thanks, but I want to use official mongo driver...

Answer (score 1):

Assuming feature is a future, just remove the await and do:

```
complete(feature.map(_.toJson))
```

Comment: If I change my code, I get an error: Error:(160, 36) value toJson is not a member of Seq[org.mongodb.scala.Document]
        complete(future.map(_.toJson()))

Comment: @bobinshtein you haven't added an unmarshaller.

See: http://doc.akka.io/docs/akka-http/current/scala/http/common/marshalling.html
http://doc.akka.io/docs/akka-http/current/scala/http/common/json-support.html

Comment: @bobinshtein your main problem is you haven't provided a marshaller. IT's necessary to convert a data type to a "wire format" i.e something you can put in a request.

Comment: Ok, It's the unmarshaller problem, but I do not understand how I can write this.

Comment: I think you might need an extra `map`: `complete(future.map(_.map(_.toJson))`. One `map` for the future, one `map` for the list.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you should not create a MongoClient instance in every request you receive.
Also, you should not block your request to get the response. The Await.result(f, duration) will block the default dispatcher and probably decrease the performance of your application drastically.

```
//other imports
import akka.http.scaladsl.server.Directives._
import akka.http.scaladsl.model.StatusCodes._

object Endpoint {
  val mongoClient: MongoClient = MongoClient("mongodb://localhost:27017,localhost:27018,localhost:27019/?replicaSet=rs0")
  val database: MongoDatabase = mongoClient.getDatabase("test")
  val collection: MongoCollection[Document] = database.getCollection("test")

  val routes = {
    pathPrefix("info") {
      pathEndOrSingleSlash {
        get {
          val future  = collection.find().limit(10).toFuture()
          onComplete(future) {
            case Success(list) =>
              complete(OK -> list.map(_.asJson()))
            case Failure(e) =>
              log.error(e)
              complete(InternalServerError -> "an error occurred while performing the request")
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

That's more likely what you're looking for. Akka HTTP works very well with Futures and this is way to go without blocking your app.